# Android capture button OnclickListener in Tab layout

Tags: android

I'm attempting to capture a button's onclicklistener event within a tab layout.

When I click on the button, the app crashes. How do you capture the button event? Usually when you use the OnClickListner on a view layout the code is as follows:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something..
                 }
    });
```

here's the setup of my tabs:

```
public class Tab1example extends TabActivity {

    private Button btn1;
    private TabHost tabhost;
    private View view1;
    private TabSpec tab1;


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater); 
    controlView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    controlView.setKeepScreenOn(true);             
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


        //Create Tab
    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();            

        TabSpec tabFan=tabHost.newTabSpec("hello");
    tab1.setIndicator("hello");
    tab1.setContent(R.id.hello);


    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what error is causing the crash and on what line? Look at your logcat output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The "thanks" at the end of your question has been edited out, since [we try to keep extraneous text like that to a minimum at SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).  Also, please edit your post to include any information you have on the error you are getting so that we can assist you better.

Comment: Your app is crashes because your `btn1` is **null**

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you forgot to initialize the button. and please would you put you xml file.

your problem would be :

1. You forgot to initialize the **Button** first before you set the `onclicklistener`   by using `b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);` where *R.id.button* is the *id* of the Button**strong text**in the *xml* file.
2. You used the `onClick` attribute in the **Button** tag in your xml file with a method name that doesn't exist in your Java code